# Ways to serialize(write Document to a text file) in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code in JRE1.6 and I want to use it in android but I'm stuck with that.

```
            OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(dom);
            format.setIndenting(true);
            XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(toWrite, format);
            serializer.serialize(dom);
```

- toWrite is a **FileOutputStream**

Comment: What issue you are facing in this ?

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectoutputStream` classes are there in android to serialize and deserialize your object. Just Google them. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) is ObjectOutPutStream